# How to store and serve (a lot) of html pages auto generated by users

Tags: java, web-applications

What I want to accomplish is the following:

I want to build a webapp in Java where once the user sign up he got auto generate his own page served by my service as:

http://localhost/userNickname
(the page should be hidden at the beginnig and require the user to publish it)

the user can also create more pages as:

http://localhost/userNickname/pageOne

http://localhost/userNickname/pageTwo

I dont want to have the scenario where when I need re-deploy my app I also need to regenerate all the pages already created by my users. I guess I need to save the pages generated by my users somewere and when I need to redeploy my app it should serve the pages again. They are static pages.

I need a starting point for this... I can figure out how to generare a html file but how to store it? how to serve it with zero downtime during deployments? It needs to be scalable. I need I kind of general architecture.

Feel free to ask if my question is not clear.
Thanks

EDIT:
Ideally the pages should be static for SEO purpose and not served on demand.

Comment: A html page is just text. You can store it anywhere you can store text, like in a file on the file system, or in a database, or in any online storage service.

Comment: Can I create a user called `.well-known`? Or `robots.txt`Or...?

Comment: *Ideally the pages should be static for SEO purpose and not served on demand.*: The search engine doesn't care (and doesn't even know) where a page comes from. A static page is just a file dynamically read from the file system, and served on demand by an HTTP server when someone sends a request for this page.